# Touchpad not even working!

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad

I have a Dell Latitude E5470 and I have an Ubuntu 20.04 as a primary OS. Today I just got a ridiculous bug in Ubuntu. Touchpad not even working anymore!! This is very weird because it didn't happen to me yesterday when I used it or even any day before it. I have been working with terminal and firefox only through shortcuts from keyboard. My mouse would move a little than stuck. Move and stuck move and stuck. It is driving my crazy because I have to work and no time to lose. How could this possibly happen and what can I do it to fix it? It looks to me like it is making a right click because when I go around my touchpad often it behaves as I would do a right click.

Thanks guys!!

Comment: sounds like a hardware issue (aka the laptop is physically broken). Is the issue present when you boot into a live USB?

Comment: @Esther hello bro, thanks for answering but weird enough the touchpad is not fixed. Not sure how much will it hold but I will try with live Ubunut if it happens again.